# Debug Assertion Failed!

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Возникает подобная ошибка, что делать?

[image: Debug Assertion Failed!]

Comment: Под отладчиком запустите, потом выше по стеку вызовов поднимитесь до своего кода.

Comment: по этому коду ничего нельзя сказать

Comment: Ой непохоже... Потому как ошибка вроде как в fputc.cpp, т.е. в чем-то связанном с выводом - а здесь вывода не видно...

Comment: Я просто понять не могу, что мне хочет сообщить эта ошибка, даёт указание на какую-то 47-ую линию. Сейчас попробую пройтись отладчиком, но я даже не знаю откуда начинать, у меня в коде 1500 строк.

Comment: Всё, нашёл. @Harry спасибо за наводку на вывод. Проблемная строка была 1428-я, я там сделал временный вывод, для отладки.

Comment: std::cout << DS [data_storage::WORD] << std::endl << DS [data_storage::TRANSCRIPTION] << std::endl;

Answer (score 3):

Подобная ошибка возникает, если пытаться выводить wchar_t или std::wstring через std::cout.

```
std::cout << L"ɔɪ" << std::endl;
std::cout << L'ð'  << std::endl;
```

Для того чтобы такой ошибки не возникало, нужно использовать std::wcout.

```
std::wcout << L"ɔɪ" << std::endl;
std::wcout << L'ð'  << std::endl;
```